# If two vectors are orthogonal, then is their covariant derivative 0?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Suppose $\langle X, Y \rangle = 0$. Then, is it true that $\nabla_X Y = 0?$ I wish to avoid using local Christoffel symbol expression (if possible), but got stuck. If false, is there a counter example?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In $\mathbb{R}^2$, let $X = \partial_x$ and $Y = x \partial_y$. Then $\langle X,Y \rangle = 0$, but $\nabla_X Y = \nabla_{\partial_x}\left( x\partial_y\right) = \partial_y \neq 0$. The answer is then no.